# BufferedImage -> int[] -> BufferedImage result in greyed black

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

I am doing some basic experimentation on picture filtering using convolution matrix, based on the [Wikipedia page about kernels in image processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)).

In order to compute the RGB transformations, I am reading the bitmap via a `BufferedImage` then get the pixels with `getRgb()`. While testing the simplest identity filter I noticed that for a specific picture I was getting some grey instead of the original black, while for some other picture, the black was OK.

After more testing, I found that without any transform, a simple `BufferedImage -> int[] -> BufferedImage` results in the greyed result.

What am I missing ? ImageMagick `identify` shows that both are 8-bit 256 colors pictures without alpha channels.

```
betty1.png PNG 339x600 339x600+0+0 8-bit Gray 256c 24526B 0.000u 0:00.000
betty2.jpg JPEG 603x797 603x797+0+0 8-bit Gray 256c 126773B 0.000u 0:00.001
```

With [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI7Ui.png) the result is as expected.
[image: result ok]

With [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYJQp.jpg), the result is unexpectedly greyed.
[image: result nok]

Here is a simple sscce test class to show the problem:

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

/* simple test class for convolution matrix */
public class CopyPic {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: CopyPic <picture_file>");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        String        imgPath   = args[0];
        String        inputName = imgPath.substring(0, imgPath.lastIndexOf("."));
        File          ifile     = new File(imgPath);
        InputStream   fis_in    = new FileInputStream(ifile);
        BufferedImage bi_in     = ImageIO.read(fis_in);
        fis_in.close();

        int width  = bi_in.getWidth();
        int height = bi_in.getHeight();
        System.out.println(String.format("%s = %d x %d", imgPath, width, height));
        int[] rgb_in = new int[width * height];
        bi_in.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, rgb_in, 0, width);

        BufferedImage bi_out = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        // for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            // for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                // bi_out.setRGB(x, y, rgb_out[y * width + x]);
            // }
        // }
        bi_out.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, rgb_in, 0, width);
        
        display(bi_in, bi_out);
        
        String outputName = inputName + "-copy.png";
        File         ofile   = new File(outputName);
        OutputStream fos_out = new FileOutputStream(ofile);
        ImageIO.write(bi_out, "PNG", fos_out);
        fos_out.flush();
        fos_out.close();
        System.out.println("Wrote " + outputName);
    }
    // use that to have internal viewer
    private static JFrame frame;
    private static JLabel label1, label2;
    private static void display(BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2) {
        if (frame == null) {
            frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setTitle(String.format("%dx%d Original / Copy", img1.getWidth(), img1.getHeight()));
            frame.setSize(img1.getWidth() + img2.getWidth(), img1.getHeight());
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            label1 = new JLabel();
            label1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img1));
            frame.getContentPane().add(label1, BorderLayout.WEST);
            label2 = new JLabel();
            label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img2));
            frame.getContentPane().add(label2, BorderLayout.EAST);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            label1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img1));
            label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img2));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Removed my comments, suddenly the code isn't displaying all black for output, not sure why.

Comment: The code works for me (I'll post my version if you like).  Be careful of the alpha channel, I'd had bad images related to the alpha channel being some value other than 0xFF (0xFF means no transparency).

Comment: I copied both of those images into GIMP, I'm not 100% certain, but I think the second image is a grey scale or RGB image with transparency.  Definitely look at that part of your algorithm.

Comment: @markspace if you have some working code or explanation different from AlexR, feel free to post! Think of the poor soul that will read in 10 years that you managed to get some working code but that solution is now list in time... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `ImageIO.read` function creates a `BufferedImage` it uses the type that it thinks is best suited. This type might not be what you expect. In particular, for a JPG image the type might not be `TYPE_INT_ARGB`.

This is the case for your second image and becomes evident when you print the type of that image:

```java
System.out.println(bi_in.getType());
```

For that image, this prints `10` on my machine, which represents [TYPE_BYTE_GRAY](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY).

So, to fix your problem you should use:

```java
BufferedImage bi_out = new BufferedImage(width, height, bi_in.getType());
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and fix. It works. My usage of a `int[]` might have been a bit naive and I was suggested by a colleague to get pixels via a `Color` instead of expecting a 3 bytes values.